# how to convert from IIS to apache httpd rewrite rule

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I saw some examples on how to convert IIS to htaccss.

I'm using httpd conf (for performance reasons) + i used online converter for IIS --> htaccess.

when converting this rule:

```
<rule name="videorecords URL" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="videorecords/*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="videorecords/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

to:

```
#RULE VIDEORECORDS URL 
RewriteRule videorecords/* videorecords/$1 []
```

the apache doesnt load and i see in the logs:
Syntax error on line 211 of httpd.conf: RewriteRule: unknown flag ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flags are blank: `[]`. So you need to either add a flag in ther (like `L`) or remove the square brackets.

Though, I don't think that the rewrite rule online converter gave you is actually what you want.

Comment: Thx!! that did it....while we at it...maybe you can help with my edited rule....this is frustrating....

Comment: @DannyValariola it depends on what you're trying to do, because it looks like the original IIS web.config rewrite is sort of broken.